# Как захватить каждую новую строку текста js

Tags: javascript, строки

Имеется текст, например стихотворение, который пользователь вводит в текстовое поле. Как мне получить строку этого стихотворения, чтобы потом, ее обработав, выдать стих также построчно. Почитал что в ASCII это символы #13#10 Как мне найти этот символ?

Answer (score 3):

Традиционно, переводы строк оформлялись по-разному в разных операционных системах, если речь идёт о текстовых файлах. В Windows это как правило #13#10, в Linux только #10. Но если вы берёте текст не из файла, а из текстового поля на веб-странице, как правило вам нужно только #10. В JavaScript этот символ обозначается как `'\n'` в строках или как `/\n/` в регулярных выражениях. Вы можете разбить текст на массив строк, например, таким образом:

```js
const arrayOfStrings = string.split('\n');
```

Comment: Все оказывается так просто!!! Спасибо огромное, с меня шоколадка. А то весь вечер прогуглил.